# How to get IMAP files into Outlook

Tags: windows, outlook, imap

I've got a backup from a Merak mail server, consisting of lots of Imap files. If I rename them .eml, I can open them with Outlook 2003 (yay!). If I do this, I can also save it into an existing account, be it POP3 or IMAP.

Now, my eventual goal is to import a batch of more than 1000 mails into an existing IMAP account. I do have [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/) available, which I could hook up into the process.

Any ideas on how to go about this a bit more efficiently than just opening and saving them 1 by 1 with Outlook?

I've considered running a local mail server and then unleash imapsync on it, but the problem is that I'm unable to find a (free) server that would host them (Merak will, of course). Btw, I'm running Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Open the eml files is Outlook Express and then export it to PST. Once you get the PST, you need to import the mails back to your mail account.